# I am having issues with my heading in my function.cpp file

Tags: c++, class, header

I have one .h which has the class in it and two .cpp, One being the main and the other holding the functions.

My complier is giving me theses errors

> - Functions.cpp: In member function âvoid Flandre::add()â:
> - Functions.cpp:10:3: error: âcinâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:12:33: error: âstrlenâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:16:6: error: âcoutâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:16:57: error: âendlâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:21:7: error: âcoutâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:21:53: error: âendlâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:27:9: error: name lookup of âiâ changed for ISO âforâ scoping [-f
> - Functions.cpp:27:9: note: (if you use â-fpermissiveâ G++ will accept your code)
> - Functions.cpp:27:16: error: âKYUUâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:32:6: error: âcoutâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:32:57: error: âendlâ was not declared in this scope
> - Functions.cpp:35:17: error: expected primary-expression before â[â token
> - Functions.cpp:37:14: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
> - Functions.cpp:38:14: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
> - Functions.cpp:39:14: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token

I think it has something to do with the #include header in Functions

Newprogram2.cpp

```
>#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "newprogram2.h"
```

Functions.cpp
Some parts are missing but I just want it to complied so I can get add() to work first.

```
#include "newprogram2.h"
```

newprogram2.h

```
#ifndef NEWPROGRAM2_H
#define NEWPROGRAM2_H
#include<string>
using namespace std;
    #endif
```

Comment: You have to `#include <iostream>` in Functions.cpp as well.

Comment: It would really help if you narrowed it down to a minimal example that reproduces the problem. This is way too much code.

Comment: You have a `cin << enterid`. It should be `cin >> enterid` to start with. You should edit the post, make right indentation so we can read easier. Also omit the parts that are not related, this is a fairly long code to read for such errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the proper headers for the functions you want to use.

For `cin`, `cout` and `endl` you need to `#include <iostream>`, you forgot to do that in your 2nd .cpp file

The compiler doesn't recognize `strlen` as a function because it is not in `<string>` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/) but in `<string.h>` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/).

I suggest you use either `size()` or `length()`, these are in `<string>`, both of these can be called on `std::string` objects.

---

```
Functions.cpp:27:16: error: âKYUUâ was not declared in this scope
```

This error shows because you try to access a variable you declared in another .cpp file. The .cpp file you are trying to access it in doesn't know this variable. You can fix that by moving the variable into the header file.

---

`Functions.cpp:27:9: error: name lookup of âiâ changed for ISO âforâ scoping`

This can be fixed by changing this

```
for(i=0;i<=KYUU;i++)
```

to this

```
for(int i=0;i<=KYUU;i++)
```

---

```
Functions.cpp:35:17: error: expected primary-expression before â[â token
Functions.cpp:37:14: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
Functions.cpp:38:14: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
Functions.cpp:39:14: error: expected unqualified-id before â[â token
```

These errors show because you try to call functions directly on a class instead of an object instantiated from that class, like this `Flandre[i].getid()`. You cannot do that, make an object instead and call the functions on the object.